# Can't embed assets in a SWF file when content is less than 4 bytes long

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, mxmlc

I am trying to compile a SWF file, using the mxmlc compiler from Apache Flex SDK 4.10.0. The program simply loads and shows text from a file called asset1.txt.

Here is my code:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import mx.core.ByteArrayAsset;

    [SWF(width="20", height="20", backgroundColor="#ff00fa")]
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed("asset1.txt", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private static var asset:Class;

        public function Main()
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            var assetBytes:ByteArrayAsset = ByteArrayAsset(new asset());
            var assetString:String = assetBytes.readUTFBytes(assetBytes.length);

            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            var tf:TextField = new TextField();
            tf.text = assetString;
            addChild(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the text contained in asset1.txt is less than 4 bytes long, all bytes from the embedded file are replaced by null bytes, otherwise everything works. For example, the text file is correctly embedded in the SWF when it contains "abcd" or "abcde", but not when it contains "ab" or "abc". Any idea?

Comment: I don't have an answer, sorry, but I am compelled to ask: why do you need to embed such a small amount of text? I can see the need to embed a large text file, but can't you just put your 2 bytes of text into a String constant?

Comment: Just a thought: have you tried using `readBytes()` instead of `readUTFBytes()`?

Comment: I am writing a SWF extraction program, so I'm creating test SWFs in order to analyze them and to understand how does Flex assets works, thereby I would like to know the reason of this behavior. Using  `readBytes()` instead of `readUTFBytes()` doesn't solve the problem, when I open the SWF in SWFWire it shows that the problem seems to come from the conversion of the asset to a DefineBinaryDataTag.

Comment: Try using `mimeType="text/plain"`, it's possible that octet-stream converter uses 32-bit reads to fill the asset, and reacts oddly upon hitting a failure immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure if `text/plain` is a supported MIME type, it isn't listed here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ffb.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f96 You could try omitting the `mimeType` parameter altogether, and the compiler will try and guess the best one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a bug of the version of Flex, Im using Flex 4.6 and test your code and is running just fine, try with a different version of the compiler. Hope that helps